# Cannot use variable in a Where-Object in a function

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, veeam

I am trying to have a function that can count jobs based on the LatestStatus value that I would pass a parameter. So far what I got:

```
Function JobCountStatus {
  Write-Output (Get-VBRJob | ?{$_.Info.LatestStatus -eq $args} | Measure-Object).Count
}
```

The issue is that as I've read somewhere there will be a subshell(?) executing the where so the argument is not passed.

If I replace the $args with a specific string like "Failed" it will work.

Is there a way to overcome this? I do not want to write separate functions for all possible values.

I would appreciate any comments - Thanks

Comment: `$args` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#args) containing an **array** of values for undeclared parameters that are passed to a function, script, or script block. You treat it as a scalar..

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, I've fixed the syntax error in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I try not to fix syntax errors in question samples but I guess that was pretty blatant that it wasn't OP's issue, considering the lack of error mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$args` is an array, not a single value. In any case, a `ScriptBlock` `{}` is an unnamed function and `$args` has it's own meaning within it, so you can't use it without some modification in something like `Where-Object`. You would have to store the elements of `$args` as another variable or multiple variables to reference within a child `ScriptBlock`. Not a huge change for this function, but for one where more parameters are expected this can result in a lot of unnecessary code which can be difficult to maintain.

---

I prefer to recommend defining named parameters in most cases, and this would be a simpler change than making the parent `$args` work in a child `ScriptBlock`:

```
Function JobCountStatus {
  Param(
    [string]$Status
  )
  ( Get-VBRJob | Where-Object { $_.Info.LatestStatus -eq $Status } ).Count
}
```

I've also made a few more changes in this function, I'll explain below:

- Use `Param()` to strongly define parameters by name. You could use the simpler syntax of `function JobCountStatus([string]$Status) {}` but for this case it's really a matter of preference for which technique to use. Using `Param()` is something I recommend as a matter of convention, but **you'll need to use either technique to get a named parameter**.
- I replaced the `$args` reference with `$Status`.
- Your use of `Measure-Object` is extraneous and so I've removed it. `Where-Object` returns a collection which already has the `Count` property.
- You can use `?` if you want but it's considered best practice to omit aliases and use full cmdlet names in scripts and modules, so I've replaced `?` with `Where-Object`.

Note that you can invoke the function/cmdlet (the difference is minimal for PowerShell-defined cmdlets) with or without the parameter, as when you don't define a positional order, the order is automatically determined in the order of declaration:

```
# Either will work
JobCountStatus -Status Running
JobCountStatus Running
```

---

Here is some more documentation you may find useful:

- [About Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-5.1)
- [About Advanced Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1)

[@Ash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036701/584676) gives some more advanced examples of what you can do with `param()` which are mentioned in the the [Advanced Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-5.1) link above. You cannot use [advanced parameter attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1) with the simple function syntax I mentioned in the first bullet point.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can just name the value when you run the function as `$args` is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#args)

```
JobCountStatus "Failed"
```

You can use an advanced function with a parameter, named or not:

```
function JobCountStatus {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [System.String]
        $Status
    )
    Process {
        (Get-VBRJob | Where-Object { $_.Info.LatestStatus -eq $Status } | Measure-Object).Count
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
JobCountStatus -Status "Failed"

# OR

JobCountStatus "Failed"
```

The latter having the same end result as just using `$args`. The only possible advantage to specifying your own parameter here is you could define a [ValidateSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#validateset-attribute) of statuses or an Enum of Status values so you can tab through them. An example of the former would be like so:

```
function JobCountStatus {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateSet("Failed", "Running", "Successful", "Unknown")]
        [System.String]
        $Status
    )
    Process {
        (Get-VBRJob | Where-Object { $_.Info.LatestStatus -eq $Status } | Measure-Object).Count
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "You can use an advanced function with a parameter, named or not"? You have to give the parameter a name if you are defining one, even with simple function definition.

Comment: As shown in the example I don't name `-Status` when executing the command, it's picked up by it's position.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, when *invoking*, not *defining*. It's worthy to mention that you don't have to define the positional order, it will be automatically determined in order of parameter declaration. I typically only recommend that approach with cmdlets that take many parameters, though it's not any less valid to do so.

Comment: It's what I believe they mean by [named and positional parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-parameters?view=powershell-7.1#positional-and-named-parameters) - `"A named parameter requires that you type the parameter name and argument when calling the cmdlet."`.

Comment: I was just confused by your wording for a sec, it makes sense now. The confusion was on my end, not in your answer.